# D3.js Node specific rectangle image placed in node circle

Tags: javascript, image, d3.js

1. **How do I place a header image above the center text in a node?**
2. **Can I give each node a different header image?** *HOW?*
3. **Will the header image beable to scale according to node size?**

---

[image]

The nodes/text are defined by size of node category/power and are scaled by:

```
  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.packageName); })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d + ")"; });;

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".2em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.className; })
      .style("font-size", "1px")
      .each(getSize)
      .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.scale + "px"; });
```

---

If I need to create individual background images to fill the circles; **What would be my options for distributing the individual images to the appropriate nodes?**

*If more information is needed please notify me below...*

Comment: You would add the image to the node in the same way as the text, with an offset that depends on the size of the circle and size of the image. All of the things you want to do are possible.

Answer (score 0):

**1. How do I place a header image above the center text in a node?**

Exactly like you did it with the text.  You need to insert an image at the correct place (you will need to calculate the offset)

**2. Can I give each node a different header image? HOW?**

I would suggest adding an imageUrl property to your source data and then bind to it in the same way that you bind to d.packageName in your code snippet above.

**3. Will the header image be able to scale according to node size?**

Yes you can scale the image according to node size, have a look at svg:transform https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform.  Specifically the "scale" attribute.

An alternative and perhaps simpler approach would be to always draw the nodes the same size but wrap each node in a "g" (group).  Then you only need to scale the whole group once.